# How to align two button elements to the right of heading for mobile view

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui

Using the following material-ui responsive [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-paperbase-t614v?file=/index.js), when shrinking the screensize to mobile view (sm), I actually would to like to position both the "Web Setup" and "?" buttons to the right of the "Authentication" heading.

At the moment, both the "Web Setup" and "?" buttons are fixed to the right of the header as you adjust the screensize.

I was looking at CSS media breakpoints but just unsure how to adjust these two elements for mobile and desktop as described above.

Comment: They're both aligned to the right side already in your codesandbox.

Comment: @NearHuscarl - this Codesandbox is not actually mine but I have used it as part of my question. Understand that it's already aligned to the right side already but in my case, I want to have it against my heading, so basically not use what this codesandbox is already doing. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Please put your code here, so I can see and explain what's wrong.